# How to create generic policies for multiple applications using NewRelic NRQL?

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

In our company we have multiple applications in the same New Relic account, each one have different alert policies according they needs.

But we would like to create generic policies, just to prevent in case someone forgot to create some important policy.

Will be something like this

```
SELECT appName FROM Transaction WHERE percentage(count(*), WHERE httpResponseCode = '404') > 0.05
```

Or... Give me the application that is returning too much 404 errors.

I know that this query don't work, but I'm trying to figure out if there are some way to have this on newrelic.

Thank you folks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Dynamic Targeting conditions](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/new-relic-alerts/defining-conditions/define-alert-conditions#dynamic-targeting-labels)? This will allow you to configure Alerts conditions based on the combination of labels targeting them. You can add labels using the agent config file, or via the UI, so you can ensure that all of your reporting apps have the correct baseline labels setup.